# How to create file within folder from TreeItem selected in TreeView with JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'm working on a TreeView in which I'm required to have folders and files. Right now the code that I have keeps creating files without taking into count the selected folder in which the file is supposed to be.
I have this:

```
TreeItem<String> newFile = new TreeItem<>(strFile);
TreeItem<String> selection = treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
/*
*
* GET FULL PATH FROM SELECTED FOLDER
*
*/
if(selection != null) {
    StringBuilder pathBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (selection = treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem(); selection != null ; selection = selection.getParent()) {
        pathBuilder.insert(0, selection.getValue());
        pathBuilder.insert(0, "/");
    }
    String path = pathBuilder.toString();
    System.out.println(path);
    createFile(path, strFile); // Create file
} else if(selection == null) {
    treeView.setRoot(newFile);
} else {
    selection.getChildren().add(newFile);
    selection.setExpanded(true);
}
```

which calls the createFile function. Said function accepts two strings, the directory name(if not null) and the file name to be created. I instantiated 3 File objects for some validation.
The first one accepts both parameters and saves the file inside X folder.
The second one to verify if folder exists, and if it does, save the file in X folder.
The third one is fr creating individual files where a folder has not been specified.

```
private void createFile(String strDirectory, String strFile) {

    File dirFile = new File(strDirectory, strFile);
    File directory = new File(strDirectory);
    File file = new File(strFile);
    boolean result;

    if(directory.exists()){
        try {
            result = dirFile.createNewFile();
            if(result) {
                System.out.println("Successfully created "+file.getCanonicalPath());
            } else {
                System.out.println("Filed creating "+file.getCanonicalPath());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        try {
            result = file.createNewFile();
            if(result) {
                System.out.println("Successfully created "+file.getCanonicalPath());
            } else {
                System.out.println("Filed creating "+file.getCanonicalPath());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm just trying to create files inside selected folder from treeview.

Comment: If the directory doesn't exist you end up calling `file.createNewFile()` which, as I understand it, only has the file name in the path. This means it's a relative path and the file should end up being created relative to the working directory. If you want the file to actually be created in the specified directory, yet said directory doesn't exist, you need to create the directory. Something like `dirFile.getParentFile().mkdirs()` followed by `dirFile.createNewFile()` should work.

Comment: Well, the thing is that I just want to be able to create files in the selected folder that is displayed in the treeView. If no folder/treeItem has been selected, then yes, create the file relatively to to working dir...but it is yet not working :/. Also, you mentioned that I'm just getting the file name, that's absolutely right. I tried doing selected.getPath? but did not work; thats why I had to do for-loop and bla bla.

Comment: Are your print statements showing the path you expect? Maybe it'd be best for you to create a [mre] that demonstrates the problem, then add it to your question via an [edit].